# How to create a child div stick to the bottom border of parent div with 50% inside the parent and 50% outside

Tags: html, css

I want a child div to stick to the bottom of parent div on the border. Something like the div below. But I want that red div should always be on the center of the border vertically, meaning the child div should stick to the bottom border of parent div with 50% inside the parent and 50% outside. So if the height of parent div changes the red still stays on the center vertically.

The way I did was to give `bottom: -20px`, but if I change the height of the parent then the div won't stay in the center vertically to the bottom border.

Here's the code I came up with.

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  background-color:black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px
}

.another-parent {
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  background-color:black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="another-parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the height and the child div will stay in place. And the parental diva needs to be given a `position: relative`.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background-color:black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: -25px;
    right: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So the problem was how I declared position property with both elements. Thanks.

Comment: I was glad to help you

Comment: @Duoro your problem was never the position, the position is fine. The only change made here is the bottom value from 20px to 25px which is half the height (use this in your code and it will be fine).

Answer (score 2):

Use `translateY(50%)` combined with `bottom:0`. This will work for any height including child and parent element:

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  background-color:black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px
}

.another-parent {
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  background-color:black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  transform:translateY(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="another-parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use percentages for perfect and responsive output.

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  background-color:black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px
}

.another-parent {
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  background-color:black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  bottom: -20px;
left: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="another-parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if it works for you.